# Vscode not able to import flask_wtf and wtforms

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am working with python3 and using flask I tried to install flask_wtf and wtforms but keep getting error from pylint on my imports. I re-installed flask_wtf, checked my path, and closed VsCode code already. Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is the content displayed by pylint when you import? What is the python environment you are currently using in VSCode?

Comment: The error says unable to import flask_wtf, wtforms, etforms_validators pylint(import-error), and using a venv

Comment: You could try to use 'pip list' in the VSCode terminal to check whether these modules have been successfully installed in the current 'venv' environment. In addition, it will be better solved if you can provide the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was solved by these steps:

1 - Install or upgrade using pip.

```
pip install -U Flask-WTF
```

2- change the python version in VScode
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To use Flask-WTF:

Open your Flask project in VS Code.
Ensure that you have set up a virtual environment for your Flask project (highly recommended).
Open the integrated terminal in VS Code (View > Terminal).
Activate your virtual environment.
Install Flask-WTF using pip within the virtual environment:

pip install Flask-WTF

Answer (score -1):

The error went away with pip install email_validator

Comment: I've installed `email_validator` and I'm still getting this issue. Any ideas? I've run `pip list` in the terminal in vscode and I can see `email-validator   1.1.2`.